# Can't login with another facebook (or google) user in spring social

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social, spring-social-facebook, spring-social-google

I'm implementing spring-social-facebook and spring-social-google. So far I've managed to login and logout user, persist it with my DB etc. So everything is working as expected. But when I'm login out and then trying to login with a different facebook (or google) user my facebook (or google) object returns first logged in user credential. Seems like its still having old connection even after I've authenticate another user.
 Below is my facebook example

**Facebook controller**

```
    @Controller
    public class LoginController {
      private Facebook facebook;
      private Google google;
      private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

      @Autowired
      private DetailService manager;

      @Autowired
      private UserService users;

      @Autowired
      public LoginController(Facebook facebook, Google google, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        this.facebook = facebook;
        this.google = google;
        this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
      }
         @RequestMapping(value = "/facebookProcessor", method = RequestMethod.POST)
              public String facebookProcessor(Model model) {
                if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class) == null) {
                  return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
                }

                String email = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile().getEmail();
                String name = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile().getName();
                String fbID = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile().getId();

                if (users.findByUsername(email) == null) {
                  User user = new User();
                  user.setUsername(email);
                  user.setName(name);
                  user.setProvider("faceboob");
                  user.setPassword(fbID);
                  user.setRoles(new String[]{"ROLE_USER"});
                  users.save(user);
                  UserDetails userDetails = manager.loadUserByUsername (user.getUsername());
                  Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (userDetails.getUsername (),userDetails.getPassword (),userDetails.getAuthorities ());
                  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
                }else if(Objects.equals(users.findByUsername(email).getUsername(),email)){
                  UserDetails userDetails = manager.loadUserByUsername (email);
                  Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (userDetails.getUsername (),userDetails.getPassword (),userDetails.getAuthorities ());
                  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
                }

                return "redirect:/entries";
              }
}
```

**SocialConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig {
  @Value("${spring.social.google.appId}")
  private String googleAppId;

  @Value("${spring.social.google.appSecret}")
  private String googleAppSecert;

  @Value("${spring.social.facebook.appId}")
  private String facebookAppId;

  @Value("${spring.social.facebook.appSecret}")
  private String facebookAppSecret;

  private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
    ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
    registry.addConnectionFactory(new GoogleConnectionFactory(
        googleAppId,
        googleAppSecert));
    registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
        facebookAppId,
        facebookAppSecret));
    return registry;
  }

}
```

**WebSecurityConfiguration** just in case..

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  DetailService userDetailsService;

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(User.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
        .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler())
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();

    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
  }

  public AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {
    return (request, response, authentication) -> response.sendRedirect("/");
  }

  public AuthenticationFailureHandler loginFailureHandler() {
    return (request, response, exception) -> {
      response.sendRedirect("/login");
    };
  }

  @Bean
  public EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension() {
    return new EvaluationContextExtensionSupport() {
      @Override
      public String getExtensionId() {
        return "security";
      }

      @Override
      public Object getRootObject() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return new SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication) {
        };
      }
    };
  }

}
```

Comment: The only way to clear connection I found so far is to submit form with "delete" method to /connect/facebook(or google). After that i can sign in with different user. 
```<form action="/connect/facebook" method="post">
            <div class="formInfo">
                <p>
                    Are you really want to logout?
                </p>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Yes, log me out</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
            </form>```
Is there any other way?